# HTML/Javascript - What is happening with '<input type=text' interactions?

Tags: javascript, html

After creating a new binding for the value property on an input, the value no longer changes when a user modifies it manually.

What is lost when the binding is changed? Does the regular user interaction use key press listeners?

I am changing the setter/getter to have an element's text automatically bound to an input's value property (using Object.defineProperty(input,'value')...

This is causing user interaction with the input to no longer change the value property. So if I, as the user, type '2' into the input, the value for the input will still be whatever it started as and not '2'.

So redefining the value property must be breaking the old setter.

Comment: can you please share the HTML and js.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Provide a code example, etc.  It's difficult to tell what you're doing and what you're actually asking.

Comment: Please clarify with your code.

Comment: could you please provide a fiddle or snippet?? I am not guessing anything.

Comment: From your topic you should change from '<input type=text' to '<input type="text"' try with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't seem to find an authoritative reference right now, but it's not generally possible/safe to update host objects (basically any object provided by the browser, instead of by JS itself) in this way.  If you insist, you might try `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` to see if you can get at the default setter before you `Object.defineProperty` and overwrite it.

More info: http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/ (see esp. "Host objects have no rules")

Comment: OK cool I wasnt sure if there was a way to get the default setter. What I am finding is that the original setter somehow links up with the 'user input change' event and causes the attribute/property to in turn be changed.What Ive currently ended up with is the 'change' event fires, but the attribute is not changed and I havent found any reference to what the change was. This is leaving me with needed to, like you said, incorporate the original setter or else mimic user interaction through key press.